# How to apply a color for labels in Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-slider

I have to apply a color for label element when I clicked and for default value for Angular Bootstrap slider.

Html:

```
<slider step="step" ticks="ticks" ticks-labels="labels" value="radius" ng-model="radius" on-slide="slide(sradius);" on-stop-slide="slide(radius);"></slider>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.ticks = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $scope.labels = [1,2,3,4,5];
     $scope.step = "1"
     $scope.sradius=3;
```

Comment: Why don't you write a function on slider change and assign color code for lables in that function?

Comment: @slacker for value how to add color,on page load

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-style** or **ng-class** using a boolean set to true when *slideStart* and to false when *slideStop*.

Those two events are described there : https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider